# "in effect" vs. "in fact"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Can anybody please distinguish the meaning of these two phrases (i.e., **in effect** and **in fact**)?

For example, how the following sentences are different in meaning:

> **In effect**, the two systems are identical.
>
> **In fact**, the two systems are identical.

or,

> His wife had, **in effect**, run the government for the past six months.
>
> His wife had, **in fact**, run the government for the past six months.

or

> **In effect**, this means we’ll all have to work longer hours for the same pay.
>
> **In fact**, this means we’ll all have to work longer hours for the same pay.

Comment: Which dictionaries did you look up the two phrases in? What specific difficulty do you have with the definitions of *in fact* and *in effect*? I suggest [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In effect" means that while something is *different* from another thing, their *effects* are very similar or identical.

"In fact" means something is accurate. It's fact. It's not just the effect, but the FACT. With the right context, this *can* be synonymous with "in effect," but absent that context, it's not. Without context forcing them to be synonymous, "in effect" tends to be a statement about something that is covert and/or indirect, while "in fact" is more firm about what was going on.

-In effect, the two systems are identical.
-In fact, the two systems are identical.

First sentence: the two systems arrive at the same place/give the same results, despite using different means to get there. Second sentence: the two systems are either exactly the same, or exactly the same in function with a few details changed. (E.g., two computer programs that have identical functions, but slightly different user interfaces.)

-His wife had, in effect, run the government for the past six months.
-His wife had, in fact, run the government for the past six months.

First: his wife was the power behind the throne, making suggestions or giving other people covert instructions, but not actually wielding power overtly. Second: His wife was giving orders and telling people what to do.

-In effect, this means we’ll all have to work longer hours for the same pay.
-In fact, this means we’ll all have to work longer hours for the same pay.

First: The situation is obfuscated so that you have to dig around to realize that the *effect* of [whatever prompted this sentence] will result in longer hours. Second: It's out in the open. The situation requires longer hours, and no one's getting any extra money for it.